# Are explicit specializations templates?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, template-specialization

According to [[temp.spec] p4](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.spec#4), a specialization is a class/function/[...] that is instantiated, or explicitly specialized. [[temp.expl.spec] p19](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.spec#temp.expl.spec-19) states that some explicit specializations are templates, which leads me to believe that explicit specializations are specialization (in the "entity generated from a template" sense), and not templates (sometimes).

My question is, are explicit specializations actual concrete entities (class/function/[...]), or are they templates. If not, what exactly are they of they aren't templates or specializations (following the definition provided by [temp.spec] p4)

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by the question "are they templates"? And how distinct would they need to be from "concrete entities"? Also, what exactly is a "concrete entity"?

Comment: @Nicol Bolas Sorry for the non-standard wording, a concrete entity would be an actual class/function/... As for what I mean by "are they templates?", It means exactly what the sentence says, is an explicit specialization of a template a template itself, or is it a specialization (in the [temp.spec] p4 sense)

Comment: What would it *mean* for an explicit specialization to be a template vs. not being a template? Besides what label to put on it, what specifically are you looking to understand about explicit specializations?

Comment: @NicolBolas As in what the implications of explicit specializations being templates would be? Well in the case of functions, mainly the fact that if they were templates, they would be added to the overload set. I know that the primary templates are only added to the overload set (see [temp.over]), so I'm assuming that it means that explicit specializations are not templates (in contrast to partial specializations, which are templates). Anyways, if they were added to the overload set during overload resolution for templates, this would result in the explicit specialization being sometimes calle

Comment: when it isn't supposed to, such as if another overload for the function existed that is a better match than the primary template that the explicit specialization is specializing.

Comment: p19 only talks of member templates of unspecialised class templates.

Comment: In short (and slightly simplified), if you use `template` to declare something (even with no template arguments, as in `template<>`), then the thing you declare is a template.

Comment: By concrete, do you mean C like, only allowed to name entities declared before, unlike templates that can refer to entities that aren't known yet?

Answer (score 2):

Your question assumes a binary status that need not exist, that an explicit specialization is either a template or a "concrete entity".

An explicit specialization may or may not be a template. A non-template explicit specialization is a specialization. As stated in the very text you quote:

> A specialization is a class, variable, function, or class member that is either instantiated or explicitly specialized.

Thus, explicit specializations behave like *specializations*. Template instantiation (implicit or explicit) creates specializations, unless the parameters match an explicit specialization. So instead, that is what gets used. But whether generated by an instantiation or by explicit specialization, specializations are treated as specializations.

So for example, different explicit specializations of the same function template are handled, not through overload resolution rules, but through template argument deduction. This is no different from any other case of specialization of that template.